# calculating zoomScaleForHeight using scrollView and imageView's bounds.height property

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm currently learning the coordinate system in ios and have encountered the following code

```
let zoomScaleForHeight = scrollView.bounds.height / imageView.bounds.height
let zoomScaleForWidth = scrollView.bounds.width / imageView.bounds.width

scrollView.minimumZoomScale = min(zoomScaleForHeight, zoomScaleForWidth)
```

`imageView` is a subview of `scrollView`.

I'm not exactly sure what is it calculating and how it is calculated. Could someone please clarify the logic behind those three lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `minimumZoomScale` represents the factor of which the image needs to be resized to in order to perfectly fit the screen without cropping any edges. Here is an image that represents the scenario:
[image: Scaling the image]

The scale is calculated by dividing the width/height of the `UIScrollView` by the width/height of the `UIImageView`. If we would now multiply the width of the `UIImageView` with its scale factor, we would get the same width as the `UIScrollView`, which is pretty much what we want to accomplish. The same counts for height.

The reason the `min()`function is needed is demonstrated by this image:
[image: Wrong Scale]

In this example, only the scale for the height is applied, the scale for width is not taken into account. By doing that the image fits perfectly in height but not in width. Therefore, both scales have to be calculated and the smaller one is to be used in order the fit the image without cropping the edges.

Comment: Is everything cleared up now? If you have any further questions please ask! :)

Comment: @Tony Stark, I can see that you are active, still any confusion?

Comment: hi chris, thanks for the very detailed answer! I have up voted, accepted, and give out the bounty to your answer. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: can't appreciate your help enough.